# How to check and validate more than one character of a string index?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

Not gonna lie this is for a project that I'm working on in college. Now, a particular section requires the input from the user to give details regarding a regestration number which needs to be 11 characters in length. Characters (8) and (10) on the index need to be letters while the rest need to be numbers. If a wrong character is input by the user, they need to be asked to input it again until correct. I am having so much trouble with what I feel should be something incredibly easy that I'm just not seeing. Here's what I've toyed around with so far (mind you this code is atrocious and uses very basic java functions as we haven't learned any more than this in my course)

```
    String regiNum;
    boolean validRegi = true;

    System.out.print("Enter registration num: ");
    regiNum = keyboard.nextLine();

    char firstChar = regiNum.charAt(8), secChar = regiNum.charAt(10);
    while(validRegi == true){
        if(!(firstChar >= 'A' && firstChar <= 'z' && secChar >= 'A' && secChar <= 'z')){
            System.out.print("Enter registration num again: ");
            regiNum = keyboard.nextLine();
            validRegi = false;
        }
    }
```

I haven't even gotten around to checking the validation for the other characters to determine whether they are digits or not. What would suit best? Maybe a do while loop? Apologies for the incredibly stupid question.

Comment: probably not the most elegant solution, but `string.matches("\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d[a-zA-Z]\\d[a-zA-Z]\\d")` should work :P

Comment: I don't think a regular expression is a helpful solution to this question - Daniel has said that he's doing basic Java, and tagged it with while loops. It seems likely that that's what his project is expected to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method does the job you wanted to do!

```
boolean isValid(String reg) {
    //check if length is 11, return false if not
    if(reg.length <11){
        for(int i=0;i<11;i++) {
            if(i==8 || i==10) {
                if(!Character.isLetter(reg.charAt(i))){
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                //check if its a number, return false if not
                if(!Character.isDegit(reg.charAt(i))){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: How would I make this loop until given the correct characters? Maybe a do-while?

Comment: yes! from a do-while. Write this method and when you call it do it inside a do-while or on click of some thing e.g. button!                                                                Attention! your upvote for answer will be highly apprecaited. :)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest thing to do would be use a for loop and check if the characters are valid one by one. You can try something like this:

```
boolean isValid(String regiNum) {
   //check if length is 11, return false if not
   for(int i=0;i<11;i++) {
      if(i==8 || i==10) {
       //check if its letter, return false if not
      }else{
       //check if its a number, return false if not
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```